# Visual Studio object browser not showing AjaxControlToolkit dll

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010. I have just noticed that the Object Browser is not showing some objects!

In my Bin folder I have, for example, the AjaxControlToolkit.dll and FreeTextBox.dll

In the Object Browser 'Browse is set to 'All Components'

The Object Browser Settings are:

- View Namespaces (ticked)
- View Containers (NOT Ticked)
- Show Base Types (ticked)
- Show Derived Types (ticked)
- Show Hidden Types and Members (ticked)
- Show Protected Members (ticked)
- Show Other Members (ticked)
- Show Inherited Members (NOT ticked)
- Show Extension Members (ticked)

Any idea why the AjaxControlToolkit.dll is not showing? And others?

They definitely used to be there as I use Object Browser all the time to inspect properties etc. expected by classes etc.

Comment: Have you referenced it?

Comment: @Kamran Shahid
Yes. If I look at Property Pages and References the AjaxControlToolkit and FreeTextBox and all the other dlls that are not showing in the Object Browser are all referenced.

The code all compiles okay. Intellisense knows those objects are there. It just seems the Object Browser, now, doesn't want to show them any more. Very frustrating. I have had to add the references to a different project so I can look at properties of the classes etc.

Comment: What type of project you have?

1, Asp.net Web Application Project Or 2, Asp.net Website Project
Or 3, Asp.net MVC Application

Comment: Asp.net Website project

Comment: That's what i were thinking that it's a website project.Can you try same with web application project?

Comment: I have lots of web site projects where the Object Browser works perfectly. Just this one where it has suddenly decided not to show the objects in the Bin folder. I don't want to convert this web site to a web application just to get something to work that should already work.

Answer (score 1):

Try one thing.
Change the framework from 4.0 to 3.5 
Then Again change the framework from 3.5 to 4.0
[I have just tried this and now able to see ajaxcontroltoolkit in the object browser]
I know it's a funny solution but worthtrying

Comment: Thanks for your input on this Kamran. Dev boxes are all being closed down and patched tonight - so I'll wait to see if things go back to normal after that first.

Comment: U r welcome Martin Smellworse. By the way i were also able to reporduce it and solved by above method by chance.Let me know what happened when you have tried this.